# How Convert arbitrary String to DataTime type

Tags: datetime, .net-core, datetime-parsing

Who could say - how convert this string for example - {YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss} into DateTime type in .net core?

I tried regex but im really not good in it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you search? It sounds to me like a task someone should have undertaken before.

Comment: Hi - Everywhere are examples like 2018-07-20 18:53:46.598000 , but i didnt this is a string with not standard format

Comment: [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-7.0) should be able to work here